# Cordova 2.2: navigator.app.exitApp() app has stopped on closing

Tags: android, cordova

I've got an app for Android published with phonegap (cordova) version 2.2.0 and am using the

```
navigator.app.exitApp();
```

call to close my application once there are no more history entries left.  This works fine for closing the app, but I'm then given a message on my physical device that states

```
Unfortunately, <app> has stopped working
```

Is there something specific that I'm missing in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logcat showed my application as not calling super.onDestroy() in my own onDestroy() method.